# java equivalent to C# ExpandoObject

Tags: java, c#

C# code example:

```
dynamic MyDynamic = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
MyDynamic.A = "A";
MyDynamic.B = "B";
MyDynamic.C = "C";
MyDynamic.Number = 12;
MyDynamic.MyMethod = new Func<int>(() => 
{ 
    return 55; 
});
Console.WriteLine(MyDynamic.MyMethod());
```

Java: ?

Any ideas why java doesn't have support for this scenario?

Comment: Because it's not a scripting language? Apparently, C# is. Hadn't heard of this feature.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you asking why Java does not have the exact same syntax or do you have a more specific scenario in mind that this code would solve and you suspect wouldn't be doable in Java?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson please have a look in my answer to mark,thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is much more strict in this case. So the short answer is no, Java doesn't have an Expando. The syntax just doesn't support that.

However there is an Expando in Groovy which is a dynamic language on top of Java.

BTW, If you're using Expando for tests, there are a lot of various Mock related solutions: EasyMock, Mockito, JMock to name a few.

Comment: @Mark thanks,it not for test. I want to serialize two instances into one json string (using gson), I did the same with using Expando in C# and that was simple and quick(and maybe dirty), in java it seems that i will need to have a compsite class to represnt those instances, class that i wont use.

Comment: @user310291 No, I just meant doesn't allow such a dynamic behavior. Dynamic invocation can be costy and cause slow behavior in runtime (just too many instructions to be run by JVM). There are alternatives like groovy or Scala. In any case the goal is not a holy-war here.

Comment: @User1234. Ok, In this case you better use Json simple. Maybe you'll find this helpful: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: OK thanks, but actually the question was born as wanted to now if there is something like Expando object as - it seems that there is not with reasoanble reasons, viva la C# ;)